# How do I fix this syntax error in my game?

Tags: python

I was creating a guessing game for practice and this syntax error came up in my code which says that my break function is outside the loop. I looked at my code and it is not outside the loop so I would appreciate it if someone could help me with my problem.

```
from random import randint

def guessing_game():

    print('Welcome to the Guessing Game')
    print('If you would like to exit, just type exit')

    while True:

        num = randint(1,9)
        guesses = []

        while True:

            try:
                guess = int(input('Please guess a number between 1 and 9: '))
            except:
                print('Please enter a numerical value')
                continue
            else:
                if guess < 1 or guess > 9:
                    print('OUT OF RANGE')
                    continue
                else:
                    if guess == num:
                        print(f'Congratulations, you guessed the correct number in {len(guesses)} guesses')
                        break
                    else:
                        if guess > num:
                            print('TOO HIGH')
                            guesses.append(guess)
                            continue
                        else:
                            print('TOO LOW')
                            guesses.append(guess)
                            continue


    play_again = input('Enter exit to stop playing: ')

    if play_again == 'exit':
        break
    else:
        continue
```

This is the error I get:

```
  File "<ipython-input-1-09b3cd044357>", line 42
    break
    ^
SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop
```

Comment: I think you just need to indent the last 6 lines so that they are in the while loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the indentation of the last few lines and make sure they're inside the 
`while` loop and it will work.

```
from random import randint

def guessing_game():
  print('Welcome to the Guessing Game')
  print('If you would like to exit, just type exit')

  while True:

      num = randint(1,9)
      guesses = []

      while True:

          try:
              guess = int(input('Please guess a number between 1 and 9: '))
          except:
              print('Please enter a numerical value')
              continue
          else:
              if guess < 1 or guess > 9:
                  print('OUT OF RANGE')
                  continue
              else:
                  if guess == num:
                      print(f'Congratulations, you guessed the correct number in {len(guesses)} guesses')
                      break
                  else:
                      if guess > num:
                          print('TOO HIGH')
                          guesses.append(guess)
                          continue
                      else:
                          print('TOO LOW')
                          guesses.append(guess)
                          continue


      play_again = input('Enter exit to stop playing: ')

      if play_again == 'exit':
        break
      else:
        continue
```

Repl: https://repl.it/repls/TurbulentImpeccableObjectdatabase

Answer (score 0):

Your line 42 is not in **2nd** **`while loop`** so that's why you getting an error make sure it will in while loop here is your line:

```
if play_again == 'exit':
    break
else:
    continue
```

**you can copy this code:**

```
from random import randint

def guessing_game():
  print('Welcome to the Guessing Game')
  print('If you would like to exit, just type exit')

  while True:

      num = randint(1,9)
      guesses = []

      while True:

          try:
              guess = int(input('Please guess a number between 1 and 9: '))
          except:
              print('Please enter a numerical value')
              continue
          else:
              if guess < 1 or guess > 9:
                  print('OUT OF RANGE')
                  continue
              else:
                  if guess == num:
                      print(f'Congratulations, you guessed the correct number in {len(guesses)} guesses')
                      break
                  else:
                      if guess > num:
                          print('TOO HIGH')
                          guesses.append(guess)
                          continue
                      else:
                          print('TOO LOW')
                          guesses.append(guess)
                          continue


      play_again = input('Enter exit to stop playing: ')

      if play_again == 'exit':
        break
      else:
        continue
```